# Why is akima::interp interpolating outside the bounds of the original data? - R

Tags: r, interpolation, tidyverse

If I am using the `quakes` dataset and the `tidyverse` to plot an interpolation using the `akima` package, I am attempting to do it like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(akima)
```

A function to interpolate:

```
## Interpolation and convert to a dataframe
dpinterp <- function(x,y,z) {
  interp_df <- interp(x = x, y = y, z = z, duplicate = "strip", extrap = FALSE, nx = 100, ny = 100)
  interp2xyz(interp_df, data.frame=TRUE)
}
```

Find the max depth for each `stations` variable. Choosing the `stations` subset less than 34 for ease of analysis:

```
quakes_sub <- quakes %>%
  filter(stations <= 34) %>%
  group_by(stations) %>%
  summarise(depth = max(depth)) %>%
  mutate(mag = 4)
```

A pipe to complete the interpolation then some data cleaning/wrangling:

```
quakes_interp <- quakes %>%
  filter(stations <= 34) %>%
  do(dpinterp(x = .$stations, y = .$depth, z = .$mag)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(z)) %>%
  rename(stations = x, depth = y, mag = z)
```

A plot to visualization and illustrate how the interpolation extends beyond the raw data points. Points in blue:

```
quakes_interp %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = stations, y = depth, z = mag, fill = mag)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  #geom_vline(data = quakes_sub, aes(xintercept = stations, colour= depth)) +
  geom_point(data = quakes_sub, aes(x = stations, y = depth, colour = mag)) +
  #stat_contour(aes(fill=..level..), geom="polygon", binwidth=0.005) + 
  #geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.5) + 
  #geom_text(data = meta_data, aes(label = Station)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="RdYlGn", 
                       na.value="white") + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

### Question: Is there a way to constrain an interpolation such that it does not extend beyond the original raw data?

### Session Info

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2       padr_0.3.0         lubridate_1.6.0    akima_0.6-2        readxl_1.0.0       dplyr_0.7.1       
 [7] purrr_0.2.2.2      readr_1.1.1        tidyr_0.6.3        tibble_1.3.3       ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 tidyverse_1.1.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] reshape2_1.4.2     haven_1.0.0        lattice_0.20-35    colorspace_1.3-2   htmltools_0.3.6    yaml_2.1.14       
 [7] rlang_0.1.1        foreign_0.8-67     glue_1.1.1         RColorBrewer_1.1-2 sp_1.2-4           modelr_0.1.0      
[13] fortunes_1.5-4     bindr_0.1          plyr_1.8.4         stringr_1.2.0      munsell_0.4.3      gtable_0.2.0      
[19] cellranger_1.1.0   rvest_0.3.2        psych_1.7.5        evaluate_0.10      labeling_0.3       knitr_1.16        
[25] forcats_0.2.0      parallel_3.4.0     broom_0.4.2        Rcpp_0.12.11       scales_0.4.1       backports_1.1.0   
[31] jsonlite_1.5       mnormt_1.5-5       hms_0.3            digest_0.6.12      stringi_1.1.5      grid_3.4.0        
[37] rprojroot_1.2      tools_3.4.0        magrittr_1.5       lazyeval_0.2.0     pkgconfig_2.0.1    swtext_0.0.1      
[43] xml2_1.1.1         assertthat_0.2.0   rmarkdown_1.6      httr_1.2.1         R6_2.2.1           nlme_3.1-131      
[49] compiler_3.4.0
```

Comment: Trying to duplicate your code, I get all z=NA after the third line of your quakes_interp pipe so it all gets filtered out and quakes_interp has zero rows. What version of the "tidyverse" are you on?

Comment: Added `sessionInfo()` though the reason was that the `dpinterp` function was problematic. Fixed now.

Comment: Your points are quakes_sub, but your interpolation is done with the full quakes (subsetted where stations <= 34). I don't know what quakes_sub is supposed to be, but it seems to be the quakes with the largest value of depth per station, so its not surprisinig there's no low values...

Comment: `quakes_sub` are the deepest points for each `stations`. Both `quakes_sub` and `quakes_interp` have been subsetted where stations <= 34 so they are equivalent in that sense. The idea is, how are values interpolated deeper than the deepest points? The points are the plot illustrate that the interpolation goes below those - and to me those blue points should constrain the interpolation. Sorry to be obtuse.

Comment: The interpolation is bounded by the convex hull of the data points (unless called with extrap=TRUE).

Comment: I think we are getting our wires crossed - if the interpolation in this case was bounded by a convex hull of the data points, why does it extend beyond (deeper) than the data points in my example? Obviously `akima::interp` is rigorous but I'm just not sure where my code is generating this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The data you are interpolating from comes from `quakes` with `stations` less than or equal to 34:

```
quakes_interp <- quakes %>%
  filter(stations <= 34) %>%
  do(dpinterp(x = .$stations, y = .$depth, z = .$mag))
```

Let's just extract those:

```
> qdata = quakes %>% filter(stations <=34)
```

And now lets plot the locations that `interp` has interpolated at:

```
> plot(quakes_interp$stations, quakes_interp$depth)
```

And now add the data points on top:

```
> points(qdata$stations,qdata$depth,col="red",pch=19)
```

And for good measure add the convex hull of the original data points:

```
> lines(
    qdata[
        chull(qdata$stations, qdata$depth),
        c("stations","depth")],lwd=2)
```

[image]

(upside-down compared to yours)

Your question was "Is there a way to constrain an interpolation such that it does not extend beyond the original raw data?" and I seem to have demonstrated that it *doesn't*, where the definition of "beyond" is the convex hull.

If you did a separate `interp` for *each* station then `interp` wouldn't go beyond the min and max value for `depth`, because you would have a one-dimensional case (mag~depth) and the convex hull in one dimension is defined by the min and max of the dimension.

`interp` is designed for interpolating on *continuous* coordinates. Your thinking that it shouldn't go beyond the max(depth) for each station is not applicable. Station is, to `interp`s eyes, a continuous coordinate like coordinates in space. In most cases with continuous coordinates the `max(x)` for any `y` is going to be the one value of `x` that goes with that `y`, because `y`, being continuous, has only unique values.

The convex hull is one answer to the question of "what is the region of interest for this set of coordinate points?". Other answers may be "the rectangular bounding box [min(x),max(x),min(y),max(y)]" or "The concave hull alpha shape defined by alpha=0.2", or "the coastline of France". If you want to restrict your region of interest that only extends as far as the max(depth) for each station then you need to clip the output of `interp` manually.

But `interp` may be totally inappropriate here - if `stations` is discrete on integers then the value of an interpolation at `stations==3.75` may be meaningless.

Actually, `interp` is probably even wronger. It interpolates based on equality of the coordinates, such that a difference of 1 station is the same as a difference of 1 depth unit. This explains the appearance of horizontal stripes in your plot. If you do the plot with an aspect ratio of 1 by adding `coord_equal()` to your `ggplot` you'll see the actual 2d surface that `interp` is working with.